# extracting days of the week from day string

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have a string like this

```
`mwftthssu`
```

Now I wanted this to be exploded into an array of

```
['m', 'w', 'f', 't', 'th', 's', 'su']
```

So what I initially did is to `str_split` them into single character array, and loop around it, then when I passed by `t`, i'll check the next letter if it was `h` if it isn't i'll push it to another array, same goes with the `s` and `su` for sat and sun

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a preg_match_all with the following regex:

```
[mwf]|th?|su?
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eL7gE4/1)

Regex matches:

- `[mwf]` - either `m`, `w`, or `f`
- `|` - or...
- `th?` - `t` or `th`
- `|` - or...
- `su?` - `s` or `su`

Here is a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/rt9D93):

```
$re = '~[mwf]|th?|su?~'; 
$str = "mwftthssu"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```